# String Concatenation Matlab

Tags: matlab, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate strings in a vector so that I can then perform a function on each individual string. I'm pretty new to MATLAB and I know that it sees each letter or space as a separate element so I'm wondering how you can get it to see each string as one element then pull each string out to perform a function on it.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is the use of [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), each cell containing a string:

```
your_array = {'one string', 'another', 'and so on'};
```

which can be accessed by

```
your_array{1} % 'one string'
your_array{2} % 'another'
```

There a some functions working with cell arrays, but for general purpose, use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to work upon each individual element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [strcat](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html)?

Since you did not define "vector", I can only assume there are three cases:

### 1. Cell array

@O'Neil has well explained this.

### 2. "Horizontal array"

In Matlab, a horizontal string array is the same as a string specified by single quotation mark:

```
myStrings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

or simply

```
myStrings = 'string1string2string3'
```

In this case, you can only extract each individual string if you have the knowledge of the length of each individual string:

```
string1 = myStrings(1 : lengthOfString1)
string2 = myStrings(lengthOfString1+1 : lengthOfString2)
string3 = myStrings(lengthOfString2+1 : lengthOfString3)
```

If your string array separates each string by delimiters:

```
myStrings = 'string1 string2, string3; string4.'
```

You can make use of `strsplit`:

```
myStringCell = strsplit(myStrings, {' ',';',',','.'})
```

The returned value `myStringCell` is a cell array of each string.

### 3. Vertical array

```
myStrings = ['mystring1'
             'mystring2'];
```

You can refer to each string by `myStrings(1,:)` and `myStrings(2,:)`.

---

The above assumes you cannot make a change to the string vector. Otherwise, I would suggest you use cell arrays.

Comment: Your example will just concatenate them _horizontally_, you will have `'mystring1mystring2'` as a result.

Comment: @Hoki, indeed. strcat is not useful for extracting an individual string from a "string vector". However, in Matlab, a horizontal string array is no different from a string made with quotation mark, i.e. `['string1', 'string2'] = 'string1string2'`. In this case the only way to extracting an individual string is to have the knowledge about the length of string beforehand, so each string can be accessed by `myArray(1:lengthOfString1)`, `myArray(lengthOfString1+1:lengthOfString2)` etc. Unless, there is a space between each string, in that case, strsplit function can be used.